# how to pass parameters to a Matlab GUI file

Tags: user-interface, matlab, ui-guidelines

i am new to matlab.  While working through the Matlab GUI, i faced a problem which is as follows.
.i want to have 2 figure files, with one figure file calling the other.   i know that just by calling the name of the 2nd fig file from the first fig file, we can call the 2nd figure. however, i also wish to send some parameters from one fig file to another.here i need to send the arguments and also obtain these parameters so as to do further processing.i havent been able to find a solution to this problem.  i would be glad if someone helps me out with this problem.
 thanking you in advance

Answer (score 7):

There are three ways I found to do this:

**Method 1:** Use [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getappdata.html) like so:

```
setappdata(0,'some_var',value)
some_other_var = getappdata(0,'some_var')
```

You would use setappdata() in the m-file for fig1 to store whatever data you wanted to pass around, and then call getappdata() in another m-file to retrieve it. The argument `0` to the two functions specifies the MATLAB root workspace, which is accessible by your program everywhere (i.e. it is global). As such, when you close your figures that data will still be available. You may want to use [`rmappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rmappdata.html) to remove them.

**Method 2:** Use [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/guidata.html):

Assuming you created your GUI with GUIDE, then you have access to a structure called `handles` which is passed around everywhere and which you can edit, and so you can do this in a GUI callback:

```
handles.some_var = some_value
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Then you can access `handles.some_var` elsewhere in some other callback (because `handles` is automatically passed into it for you) in your other m-file:

```
some_other_var = get(handles.some_var)
```

**Method 3:** Use [`UserData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/userdata.html):

Store the variable you want from your first figure:

```
set(name_of_fig, 'UserData', some_var)
```

Then to get it from your other one:

```
some_other_var = get(name_of_fig, 'UserData')
```

---

(Disclaimer: My actual knowledge of MATLAB is not all that great, but it helps to be able to find good resources like [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/2d0beabe03b79d71/37ed95b7e574f824?show_docid=37ed95b7e574f824&hl=en&pli=1) and [this](http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/matlab-gui-how-to-easily-share-data-between-two-separate-guis/), and even [this from the official docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f5-998352.html). What I've written here *may* be wrong, so you should definitely consult the docs for more help.)

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this (assuming you're using the GUI builder **GUIDE**).

Let's say that your figures/m-files are named **firstFigure.fig/m** and **secondFigure.fig/m**. In the code of **firstFigure**, just call **secondFigure** and pass your parameters as arguments:

```
someNumber = 1;
someText = 'test';
aMatrix = rand(3);

secondFigure(someNumber, someText, aMatrix);
```

The arguments will be available to **secondFigure** as a variable **varargin** in the callback functions

```
function varargout = secondFigure(varargin)
```

and

```
function secondFigure_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
```

**varagin** is a cell structure; use **cell2mat** and **char** to convert it back:

```
theNumber = cell2mat(varargin(1));
theText = char(varargin(2));
theTextAgain = cell2mat(varargin(2));
theMatrix = cell2mat(varargin(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171989

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to wrap the parameters in a cell array and send them directly to the GUI constructor. A call with two parameters might look like:

```
figure2({param1, param2})
```

Then you can unpack the arguments in the opening function (figure2_OpeningFcn) with code like:

```
handles.par1 = varargin{1}{1};
handles.par2 = varargin{1}{2};
```

These lines must be placed somewhere before the line that says `guidata(hObject, handles);`. Then you can access `handles.par1` and `handles.par2` directly in all the other callbacks.

I assume you are using GUIDE to generate your GUI. You can find figure2_OpeningFcn in figure2.m which will be located in the same directory as figure2.fig.

Note: you can also return values from a figure, `returnvalue = my_figure({my_input})`. If you'd like instructions on that too, leave a comment and I'll extend my answer.